# date to epoch conversion

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me how to convert date to epoch in java.
e.g. 2011-05-01 13:12:20 IST or 2011-05-01 14:11:10 PST to epoch.
I am able to convert using 2011-05-01 13:12:20 format but when I use timezone alongwith it I am not getting correct result.

Comment: Please show the code you tried, the result you got and what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a string pattern that matches the date format you have.  The "Date and Time" section and the "Examples" section should give you more than enough help on how to construct your date format string

Then simply do the following to get your date (with the appropriate date format string).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date = sdf.parse("15/01/2012");
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Using the java.time classes.

```
String input = "2011-05-01 13:12:20".replace( " " , "T" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

If by “epoch”, you mean a count of whole seconds or milliseconds from the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (often referred to as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), then interrogate the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object via an extracted [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object.

```
long wholeSecondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```